# Where does the usual topology on $R^n$ fit into the lattice of topologies?

Tags: general-topology, lattice-orders

I am trying to understand how the usual topology on $R^n$ fits into the lattice of topologies. In particular, I am wondering what is the greatest lower bound and least upper bound.

I have been asked to clarify the question. Thus, (borrowing in considerable part from [Joel David Hamkins](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15841/how-do-the-compact-hausdorff-topologies-sit-in-the-lattice-of-all-topologies-on)) I will expand it as follows:
This question is about the position of the usual topology in the space of all topologies on a fixed set X. We may order the topologies by refinement, so that τ ≤ σ just in case every τ open set is open in σ. Equivalently, we say in this case that τ is coarser than σ, that σ is finer than τ or that σ refines τ. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies.) The least element in this order is the indiscrete topology and the largest topology is the discrete topology.

One can show that the collection of all topologies on a fixed set is a complete lattice. In the downward direction, for example, the intersection of any collection of topologies on X remains a topology on X, and this intersection is the largest topology contained in them all. Similarly, the union of any number of topologies generates a smallest topology containing all of them (by closing under finite intersections and arbitrary unions). Thus, the collection of all topologies on X is a complete lattice.

For example the compact topologies are closed downward in this lattice, since if a topology τ has fewer open sets than σ and σ is compact, then τ is compact, and the Hausdorff topologies are closed upward, since if τ is Hausdorff and contained in σ, then σ is Hausdorff. Thus, the compact topologies inhabit the bottom of the lattice and the Hausdorff topologies the top.

The lattice has atoms, since we can form the almost-indiscrete topology having just one nontrivial open set (and any nontrivial subset will do). It follows that every topology is the least upper bound of the atoms below it.

My question then is, considering the usual topology on $R^n$, what is the GLB and the LUB of this topology in the lattice? Or, if this is not known, what topologies are known to be comparable to it in the upward and downward directions?

Comment: @D What about the discrete and the trivial topology?

Comment: @DonThousand To your comment "Point is, a set of topologies on a space will have a greatest lower bound (the intersection) but will not always have a least upper bound" ----- Isn't "the topology generated by a set of sets" a well-defined closure operator?  That would seem to make the set of topologies on $\mathbb{R}^n$ a complete lattice.

Comment: @DonThousand The lattice of all topologies on a set always has a naximum and a minimum (in contrast to general lattices). But the OP's question is too vague to give an answer. I shall therefore vote to close it.

Comment: I am not sure what would be meant by the "greatest lower bound" or "least upper bound" on the lattice of topologies. But in general, the greatest element is the discrete topology and the least element is the trivial topology (for any set, not just $\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: Some where in the middle.

Comment: @PaulFrost Are the discrete and trivial topologies the least and greatest bounds? Should I perhaps phrase it instead in terms of covers?

Comment: @all Let me try to put this in plain words and perhaps you guys can help me understand how to better pose the question. Given that the usual topology is an element in the lattice of topologies partially ordered by inclusion, and given that it is a complete lattice, it lies somewhere between the discrete topology above and the indiscrete topology below. What I am trying to understand is what topologies are above it and what below it, other than the discrete and indiscrete..

Answer (score 1):

For n = 1, the lower and upper limit topologies and the  add an additional open set topology are finer than the usual R.

A topology of a partition of R is coarser provided at least one partition part is multipoint.  Other coarser spaces are the open and closed ray topologies, the cofinite and cocountable topologies.  A coarser, uncountable, Hausdorff space eludes me.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I was aware of some of those (cofinite), but not the others. I've been unable to find anything in the literature that directly addresses this question. Can you point me anywhere? I'm not a mathematician, but the question bears on a research project in another discipline. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2320588 seems relevant, but I'm struggling with it.